# How to create a pivot table with columns to rows and rows to columns using mysql

Tags: mysql

Got a table in mysql with the below columns and rows

```
Table1
-------------------------------------------------------------
date_time           Place         Cat 1 Cat 2   Cat 3
-------------------------------------------------------------
5/14/2019 3:54           FUJ                     Yes
5/14/2019 4:19           FUJ                Yes      Yes
5/15/2019 1:22           FUJ                     Yes
5/14/2019 11:08          MUM            Yes Yes 
5/15/2019  16:34:00 PM   MUM                     Yes
```

Need help in getting a pivot table as below desired output

---

```
Places  Categories  5/14/2019   5/15/2019
-------------------------------------------------------------
FUJ Cat 1               0               0
    Cat 2               1               0
    Cat 3               2               1
MUM Cat 1               1               0
    Cat 2               1               0
    Cat 3               0               1
```

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 0):

A better schema might look as follows:

```
-----------------------------
date_time           Place Cat
-----------------------------
2019-05-14 03:54:00 FUJ     3
2019-05-14 04:19:00 FUJ     1
2019-05-14 04:19:00 FUJ     3
2019-05-15 01:22:00 FUJ     2
2019-05-14 11:08:00 MUM     1
2019-05-14 11:08:00 MUM     2
2019-05-15 16:34:00 MUM     3
```

This isn't an answer, but it is a better place to start; the rest of the problem would ordinarily be solved in your application code/presentation layer (i.e. php)

Comment: i wanted to download the same report date wise, and category wise and place wise

Comment: Yep, that would just be `SELECT * FROM the_above ORDER BY place, category, date_time`. Everything else would typically be handled in your application code.